# Why won't the newline print? The commented part doesn't part

Tags: c

The line `//if(date == 7){` fails to run the inner block and I don't understand why.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void){
  int day,date,days,start_date,first_week_start;

  printf("\nEnter number of days in the month:");
  scanf("%d", &days);
  printf("Enter the day the calendar starts (Sun = 1, Sat = 7):");
  scanf("%d", &start_date);
  printf("\n");
  
  while(start_date > 1){
    printf("  ");
    start_date = start_date - 1;
    date = date + 1;
  };

  for(day = 1; days >= day; ++day, ++date ){
    int day_of_the_week;
    // While the day of the week is less tha 7, number are printed
    // Once date 7 is met, prints on a new line and date is reset 
    printf("%d  ", day);
    //if(date == 7){  >>>Not Working
    if(date % 7 == 0){
      printf("Newline \n");
      date = 0;
    };
  };
};
```

Comment: Note: you really don't need all of those semicolons after your braces.

Comment: `date` is uninitialized.

Comment: ⟼This code could benefit greatly by adopting an [indentation style](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indentation_style) and applying it consistently. Indentation conveys structure and intent which makes it easier for us to understand your code without having to invest a lot of time deciphering it, and it can also make mistakes more obvious as they stand out visually.

Comment: When something like `if (date == 7)` doesn't work as expected, the thing to do is run the program in a debugger, and look at the value of `date`, or alternatively, just change `printf("%d  ", day);` to `printf("day=%d date=%d\n", day, date);`

Comment: You can't expect to be able to comment/uncomment a line featuring an open brace and still have the code compile. At least one of the versions is going to be wrong, as a rule of thumb.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the `date` variable is not initialized, you're encountering undefined behavior.

Strongly suggest you declare and initialize variables when you need them, and restrict the scope of variables when possible.